# No preview for icons in VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, icons

- VSCode Version: 1.52.1
- OS Version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

When pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> normally a window with additional information pops up and when doing so next to specifying an icon, it shows a preview for the currently targeted icon.
ATM it does not show this preview in the popup, but after saving, closing and reopening the file it shows the tiny leading preview in front of the code.

[image: Screenshot: no preview for icons]

Trying to fix this abnormal behaviour, I discovered, that it also does not work properly with Cupertino Icons.

Any heads up?

Answer (score 1):

There should be an arrow appearing when you hover on the right side of the tooltip stating "read more". Simply click once and therefore the icon preview should always appear.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xThe.png

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe it's hard to see, but I already clicked on the arrow, as you can see in the attached image.